# Dynamic remarketing shows random products from the feed

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

My remarketing campaign shows random products from the feed in Merchant Center, rather than the actual product the customer visited.

I implemented the remarketing tag with Tag Manager and when i use preview mode and go to a products page everything works fine and the custom parameters are ok.
[image]
Campaign works and is showing ads, but the products in the ads are random from the feed. ecomm_prodid is the same as ID in the feed so that´s not the problem.

Tag Assistand are not showing any request data for the remarketing tag. However the right custom parameters shows fine in the Tag manager tags DataLayer. Could this be a part of the problem? Or does'nt Tag assistant show custom parameters on remarketing tags implemented with Tag Manager?

[image]

Comment: did you ever get this figured out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No. It is sad. I got it working by not using Google Tag Manager however. I really liked the concept of GTM, but since it was not working I had to go back to use the old classic code snippet way